# php - error document combined with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, errordocument

I'm trying to set ErrorDocument 404 page by using `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`, but it does not work, because I have mod_rewrite enabled... Is there some chance to check, if the page exist before it falls to mod_rewrite? I'm posting my htaccess down bellow... It is caused by last rule, which redirects everything to product.php - `RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ product.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]`

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteRule ^(admin|subdom)($|/) - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^coming-soon/?$ coming-soon.php [L]

RewriteRule ^tabulky-velikosti/?$ tabulky-velikosti.php [L]
RewriteRule ^o-bambusu/?$ o-bambusu.php [L]
RewriteRule ^vymena-zbozi/?$ vymena-zbozi.php [L]
RewriteRule ^doprava-a-platba/?$ doprava-a-platba.php [L]
RewriteRule ^obchodni-podminky/?$ obchodni-podminky.php [L]
RewriteRule ^ochrana-osobnich-udaju/?$ ochrana-osobnich-udaju.php [L]
RewriteRule ^o-nas/?$ onas.php [L]
RewriteRule ^kontakt/?$ kontakt.php [L]
RewriteRule ^faq/?$ faq.php [L]
RewriteRule ^kosik/?$ cart.php [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/?$ blog.php [L]
RewriteRule ^search/?$ search.php [L]

RewriteRule ^blog/tag/(.*)/? blog.php?tag=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)/? blogDetail.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/? search.php?s=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^zaciname/?$ category.php [L]
RewriteRule ^nakupovat/?$ category.php [L]
RewriteRule ^kategorie/?$ category.php [L]
RewriteRule ^prozkoumat/?$ category.php [L]

RewriteRule ^kategorie/((?:pan|dam|det)ske)-pradlo/?$ category.php?gender=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ product.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Is there anything I can do with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way in which you can do this. You set the 404 via a `RewriteRule` and then set the `ErrorDocument` via URL instead of the file:

```
RewriteRule ^404/?$ 404.php
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.example.com/404.php
```

Place it below your last rule and remove the `[L]` flag from your last rule.

This method *shouldn't* cause an issue with `mod_rewrite`. Make sure you clear your cache **before** testing this.

**EDIT**

You could just add a condition to the last rule to exclude the `404.php` page?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/404.php
```

That would stop the Rewrite from happening for that page, so your code would be:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/404.php
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ product.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it still dont work... Posting below edited last lines... `RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ product.php?url=$1 [QSA]

RewriteRule ^404/?$ 404.php
ErrorDocument 404 https://ecobamboo.cz/404.php` ... is it done correctly?

Comment: It is, perhaps just try using the `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`, but once again posted below the last rule and with the `[L]` flag removed. The L flag stands for `LAST` and stops other rules running past it. Which is why I feel that might be part of the problem.

Comment: Infact, see my edit @stepik21 - that should fix your problem and allow you to keep the `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` that you had originally :)

Comment: would it be possible to hit you up on some chat please? :) I'm still having problems with that... Thanks a million for helping me out!

Comment: Sure, no problem. I've created a chat room for us to continue talking about this. Enter it [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176539/stepik21). Just fyi, I am at work so my responses will be intermittent :)